# Objective C- define in C or objective C

Tags: objective-c, c

I am a beginner so please bear with me. First of all, is all the NS stuff (NSArray, NSString, etc) objective-C specific?

Also, I'm confused about creating things in C or in objective-C. When do you use one or the other?

For example, which cases would I use the below:

```
NSArray *germanCars = @[@"Mercedes-Benz", @"BMW", @"Porsche", @"Opel", @"Volkswagen", @"Audi"];
```

or:

```
NSString *germanCars[] = {@"Mercedes-Benz", @"BMW", @"Porsche", @"Opel", @"Volkswagen", @"Audi"};
```

Thanks

Comment: definitely the first one; later when you start to realize the possibilities of `NSArray` and you start thinking in complex model layers (including permanent storing) you will never even consider the second one as a reasonable option.

Comment: Yes, the `NS` stuff is pretty much objc (or better Foundation/AppKit related. You would usually work with `NSArray`s, so your first attempt is better suited for Cocoa.

Comment: @HAS if stuff prefixed with NS are objc, how come the 2nd snippet above uses NSString?

Comment: You're creating a C-array of pointers to Objective-C objects (in this case `NSString`s).

Comment: ... not to mention the second won't even compile if it's within a pure C implementation file (`.c`).

Comment: user1389811, don't forget to select one of these as the answer. This less everyone on the site know that your question has an accepted answer. I see that none of your questions has an accepted answer. If you keep doing that, people will eventually stop answering your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NS stuff comes originally from the NeXTSTEP operating system: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NeXTSTEP

Steve Jobs ran NeXT, and brought the stuff over to Apple when he returned there.

When working with Mac OS or iOS, it's part of the Cocoa framework. Objective-C is just the language these things are written in.

As for your coding question, use the first. You want to use the Cocoa constructs as much as possible. Cocoa is a mature, well-designed API and you will find a lot of tasks will be easier if you do things with that style.

Answer (score 3):

The stuff prefixed with `NS` is specific to the Cocoa frameworks, Foundation and AppKit. They were originally designed for Objective-C, but they are accessible from other languages if they have a binding. The obvious one these days is Swift, but they can also be accessed from Python using PyObjC, etc.

In general, you should prefer the Cocoa collection classes (i.e. `NSArray`) over C-style types. They are higher level and thus provide better abstractions and functionality. You would use a C-style array only for APIs which require it, which are relatively rare.

Comment: ... and C++ via Objective-C++.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is an NSArray object, containing several NSString objects. Your second example is an ordinary C array, containing several NSString objects.

You will find very few methods in the Cocoa library that accept C arrays of objects. And NSArray have a huge range of useful functionality that C arrays don't have.